# Группировка записей по полю

Tags: php, sql

Как написать запрос по SQL, чтобы он сгруппировал записи по полю и в результат вернул массив?

Например есть таблица с историей заказов.
Есть поля `ID`, `ID_CLIENT`, `SUMMA`, `ORDER`:

- `ID` = Это номер заказа
- `ID_CLIENT` = ID клиента которому принадлежит заказ
- `SUMMA` = Сумма заказа
- `ORDER` = Список заказа

При обычным запросе `select * from order group by id_client` возвращает по одному заказу с клиента.

Мне нужно чтобы в итоге я получил трехмерный массив наподобии этого:

- `$list[ID_CLIENT][ID_ORDER]` - Массив с информацией о заказе
- `$list[ID_CLIENT]` - Массив с заказами
- `$list` = Массив с клиентами

Comment: только ручками в php-коде собираете, `group_concat` имеет ограничения

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для этого подойдет PDO и одна из его волшебных констант, а именно - [PDO::FETCH_GROUP](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/fetch#FETCH_GROUP), для чего первой колонкой надо будет выбрать id_client. В этом случае все записи сгруппируются ровно так как надо:

```
$sql = "SELECT id_client, * FROM ...";
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

GROUP BY использовать не нужно

Comment: Боюсь во втором измерении ID_ORDER не будет (там будет просто массив 0,1,2 ...), а ТС его хочет ...

Comment: Он там не нужен.